# [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm building my CRUD with Laravel & VueJS. When I submit the creation form, I'm getting this message error : [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

Here, my createUser method :

```
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            user: {
              firstname: '',
              lastname: '',
              email: '',
              password: ''
            },
            errors: [],
            users: [],
            update_user: {}
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.readUsers();
    },
    methods: {
        createUser(){
            axios.post('user', {
                firstname: this.user.firstname,
                lastname: this.user.lastname,
                email: this.user.email,
                password: this.user.password
            }).then(response => {
                this.reset();
                if (response.data.message == "Error"){
                  this.errors.push("L'utilisateur que vous tentez d'ajouter existe déjà!")
                }else{
                  this.users.push(response.data.user);
                }
            })
        },
        readUsers(){
            axios.get('user')
                .then(response => {
                    this.users = response.data.users;
                });
        },
    }
}
```

And here, the table when I display all users from DB. Display users works correctly.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive" v-if="users.length > 0">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Nom</th>
      <th>Prénom</th>
      <th>Adresse e-mail</th>
      <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr v-for="(user, index) in users">
      <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.lastname }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.firstname }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
      <td>
          <button @click="initUpdate(index)" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Éditer</button>
          <button @click="deleteUser(index)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Supprimer</button>
      </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My User model from Laravel here :

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'email',
        'password'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

And for the finish, my UserController method :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'firstname' => 'required',
        'lastname' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    $user = User::create([
        'firstname'     => request('firstname'),
        'lastname'      => request('lastname'),
        'email'         => request('email'),
        'password'      => Hash::make(request('password'))
    ]);

    return response()->json([
        'user'    => $user,
        'message' => 'Success'
    ], 200);
}
```

Comment: `this.readUsers();` where is this method defined?

Comment: sorry, I tought that I have write it. Post updated with the method.

Comment: post the user model and controller method  or do a console.log after getting the user  ```axios.get('user')
                .then(response => {
                    this.users = response.data.users; console.log(this.users);
                });```  open browser console and tell me what you get there

Comment: `axios.get('user')` change that to `axios.get('/user')` (users maybe?)

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi I have edit my post with model and controller.

Comment: @btl I already tried that, and nothing change..

Answer (score 2):

The create() method returns the model. So you need to transform user collection a bit,

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'firstname' => 'required',
        'lastname' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    $user = User::create([
        'firstname'     => request('firstname'),
        'lastname'      => request('lastname'),
        'email'         => request('email'),
        'password'      => Hash::make(request('password'))
    ]);

    return response()->json([

        'user'    => [
          'id'=>$user->id, 
          'firstname'=>$user->firstname,
          'lastname'=>$user->lastname,
          'email'=>$user->email
        ],

        'message' => 'Success'

    ], 200);
}
```